# Output difference of images to text file

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I am attempting to compare several sets of images to a reference set. While I have been toying with the RMSE metric in Imagemagick I am quite open to seeing other ways of going about it. Suppose I have folder A, with 5 images. These same 5 images, with slight alterations, exist in folders B, C, D and E. What I would like to do is compare the files in B with A, C with A and so on and output the result to a file that I can later use in a spreadsheet. This is my current solution but it's not very pretty, outputs only to the command line, can only compare one folder with the reference and wouldn't be practical for thousands of images.

```
#!/bin/bash

folder1=A
folder2=B

cd "$folder1"
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.png; do
  file1="$f"
  file2="$folder2/$f" 
  compare -metric RMSE "$file1" "$file2" NULL:
done
```

With the output `1754.1 (0.0267658)2148.58 (0.0327852)2417.38 (0.0368868)2488.65 (0.0379744)2113.88 (0.0322557)`. I would appreciate any help with this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change working directory to directory that contains A, B, C, D and E before running this

```
for folder in B C D E; do
    for image in A/*.png; do
        compare -metric RMSE "$image" "$folder/${image##*/}" NULL:
    done &> "${folder,}.txt"
done
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right track, but it has a few issues. It only outputs into the terminal even when trying to output to a text file, and it would output everything into one file, I would prefer to have it output into several files (for example, b.txt, c.txt and so on).